# How to Take Part of a String using One of the T-SQL Text Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following snippet:

```
 CONVERT(varchar, FLOOR(ROUND((DATEDIFF(minute, shiftStart.timeEntered, shiftEnd.timeEntered) - DATEDIFF(minute, 
                      lunchStart.timeEntered, lunchEnd.timeEntered)) * 1.0 / 60, 2, 1))) + ':' + CONVERT(varchar, ROUND(ROUND(DATEDIFF(minute, shiftStart.timeEntered, 
                      shiftEnd.timeEntered) * 1.0 / 60, 2, 1) % 1 * 60, 0)) AS WorkingHours
```

The above code prints hour and minute in the following format:

```
4:30.000000
7:40.000000
8:1.000000
```

I need to rid of the . and next 0's so i get the following format:

```
4:30 (4 hours and 30 mins)
7:40 (7 hours and 40 minutes)
8:1 (means 8 hours and 1 minute)
```

.0000 Doesn't harm but it gives bad look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the minutes portion to INTeger before converting to VARCHAR to drop the decimal values:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
        CONVERT(INT, ROUND(ROUND(DATEDIFF(minute, shiftStart.timeEntered, shiftEnd.timeEntered) * 1.0 / 60, 2, 1) % 1 * 60, 0)))
```

Full example:

```
CONVERT(varchar, FLOOR(ROUND((DATEDIFF(minute, shiftStart.timeEntered, shiftEnd.timeEntered) - DATEDIFF(minute, lunchStart.timeEntered, lunchEnd.timeEntered)) * 1.0 / 60, 2, 1))) + ':' + 
CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, ROUND(ROUND(DATEDIFF(minute, shiftStart.timeEntered, shiftEnd.timeEntered) * 1.0 / 60, 2, 1) % 1 * 60, 0))) AS WorkingHours
```